# Attention is all you need, keeping only the encoding part for video classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to modify a code that could find in the following [link](https://github.com/Lsdefine/attention-is-all-you-need-keras) in such a way that the proposed `Transformer` model that is related to the paper: [all you need is attention](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) would keep only the `Encoder` part of the whole `Transformer` model. Furthermore, I would like to modify the input of the `Network`, instead of being a sequence of text to be a sequence of images (or better-extracted features of images) coming from a video. In a sense, I would like to figure out which frames are related to each other from my input and encode that info in an output embedding in the same way that is happening to the `Transformers` model.

The project as it is in the link provided is mainly performing sequence-sequence transformation. The input is text from one language and the output is text in another language. The main formation of the model is happening in the lines [386-463](https://github.com/Lsdefine/attention-is-all-you-need-keras/blob/master/transformer.py). Where the model is initialized and the compile of the Model is happening. For me I would like to do something like:

```
#414-416 
self.encoder = SelfAttention(d_model, d_inner_hid, n_head, layers, dropout)
#self.decoder = Decoder(d_model, d_inner_hid, n_head, layers, dropout)
#self.target_layer = TimeDistributed(Dense(o_tokens.num(), use_bias=False))
#434-436
enc_output = self.encoder(src_emb, src_seq, active_layers=active_layers)
#dec_output = self.decoder(tgt_emb, tgt_seq, src_seq, enc_output, active_layers=active_layers)  
#final_output = self.target_layer(dec_output)
```

Furthermore, since I would like to combine the output of the `Encoder` which is the output of `MultiHeadAttention` and `PositionwiseFeedForward` using an `LSTM` and a Dense layer which will tune the whole `Encoding` procedure using classification optimization. Therefore, I add when I define my model the following layers:

```
self.lstm = LSTM(units = 256, input_shape = (None, 256), return_sequences = False, dropout = 0.5)
self.fc1 = Dense(64, activation='relu', name = "dense_one")
self.fc2 = Dense(6, activation='sigmoid', name = "dense_two")
```

and then pass the output of the `encoder`, in line [434](https://github.com/Lsdefine/attention-is-all-you-need-keras/blob/master/transformer.py) using the following code:

```
enc_output = self.lstm(enc_output)
enc_output = self.fc1(enc_output)
enc_output = self.fc2(enc_output)
```

Now the video data that I would like to replace the text data provided with the Github code, have the following dimensionality: `Nx10x256` where N is the number of samples, 10 is the number of frames and `256` the number of features for each frame. I have some difficulties to understand some parts of the code, in order to successfully, modified it to my needs. I guess, that now the Embedding layer is not necessary for me anymore since it is related to text classification and NLP.

Furthermore, I need to modify the input to [419-420](https://github.com/Lsdefine/attention-is-all-you-need-keras/blob/master/transformer.py) to be sth like:

```
src_seq_input = Input(shape=(None, 256,), dtype='float32') # source input related to video
tgt_seq_input = Input(shape=(6,), dtype='int32') # the target classification size (since I have 6 classes)
```

What other parts of the code do I need to skip or modify? What is the usefulness of the `PosEncodingLayer` that is used in the following line:

```
self.pos_emb = PosEncodingLayer(len_limit, d_emb) if self.src_loc_info else None
```

Is it needed in my case? Can I skip it?

After my modification in the code I noticed that when I run the code, I can check the loss function from the `def get_loss(y_pred, y_true)`, however, in my case it is crucial to define a loss for the classification task that returns also the accuracy. How can I do so, with the provided code?

**Edit:**
I have to add that I treat my input as the output of the Embedding layer from the initial NLP code. Therefore, for me (in the version of code that functioned for me):

```
src_seq_input = Input(shape=(None, 256,), dtype='float32')
tgt_seq_input = Input(shape=(6,), dtype='int32')

src_seq = src_seq_input

#src_emb_ = self.i_word_emb(src_seq)
src_emb = src_seq
enc_output = self.encoder(src_emb, src_emb, active_layers=active_layers)
```

I treat `src_emb` as my input and completely ignore `src_seq`.

**Edit:**

The way that the loss is calculated is using the following code:

```
def get_loss(y_pred, y_true):

    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, 'int32')
    loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_true, logits=y_pred)
    mask = tf.cast(tf.not_equal(y_true, 0), 'float32')
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(loss * mask, -1) / tf.reduce_sum(mask, -1)
    loss = K.mean(loss)
    return loss

loss = get_loss(enc_output, tgt_seq_input)
self.ppl = K.exp(loss)
```

**Edit:**
As it is the loss function (**sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits**) returns a loss score. Even if the whole procedure is about classification. How, can I further, tune my system to return also the accuracy?

Comment: First of all, as in your last question what you deleted turned out, that you have to first define, what do you want to choose to get the targets of your classifying task. Without this target (labels) your model can not classify. So, what is the target of your classifier? Based on the type of this target(labels) we can step forward to choose the loss function.

Comment: The target of my loss is the labels that I have for video classification. They are having the size of video samples and for each one 6 dimensions (categorical encoding for each class). In the code, I posted are represented by tgt_seq_input.

Comment: @Geeocode I am comparing tgt_seq_input and the output to enc_output in order to calculate the loss.

Comment: Ok I understand. The video frames will be feeded sequentially i.e. frame by frame of the same video each? Then the next video etc?

Comment: @Geeocode Yes exactly. So I have let's say 10.000 videos for each one 20 frames and each frame is represented with 256 features. For each sample video I have one annotation. Now, my main confusions are if I can skip the PosEncodingLayers and if the loss as it is in the main code, makes sense for me.

Comment: I think, that it depends on the classifying target and object. We only need PosEncodingLayers if the sequence order has some meaning. If the target bounds to some static property e.g. "there is an apple in the video", then we don't need it. If the target is some like "moving left", then we will need, as we want to get information about the order of frames, which means "moving right" in reverse order in this case.

Comment: @Geeocode in my case, I have the order of frames in the video. 20 frames from a video of one and half-second. So I am not sure that there is a need for this layer. I am also very puzzled since the code included the Embedding layer which is made for text and I do not know how can I taking advantage of it in my case that I have videos instead.

Comment: Doesn't matter that you "have the order" as if you don't use this layer your model will not learn i.e. encode dynamic properties like movement. As I said it depends on what target you want to distinguish your videos based on. So if your labels are not about dynamic information you will not need it. Regarding embedding I will be back later, as I have to go now. Until then please think twice about the first section, because it is important.

Comment: @Geeocode my labels are static and represent emotions.

Comment: If your emotions are static, what is suspicious for me as a smile backwards is a said face, but you know it, then you don't need nothing from sequence type learning process. You just should build some tpye of convolution network, if you don't want then don't use decoder. At the and of the model use categorical crossentropy, pass all the frames through the model at trainnig, then at prediction pass all the frames of the same video through the model and take the mean of the predictions. It is a "simple" classifier task without any sequence base unit.

Comment: This is the way I am trying to solve it. I am trying to input a sequence and in the output to perform a simple classifier that will tune the whole system. Therefore, in my code, I commented out all the decoder part and replace it with the classifier. MY question except for the Embedding layer in the input of Encoder is whether I need to have the same loss as the example or I need to replace it.

Comment: Ok one more question, why the frames have only 1D 256 features?

Comment: @Geeocode this is just an example. I can modify the output of my Cnn network to output a different dimension. This I guess is a parameter that I can tune. However, is there any rationale about what should be the dimensionality?

Comment: In lack of the 2nd D you loose a lot spatial information. So it should be 2D, say 128 x 128 or other depending on the raw material.

Comment: @Geeocode yes but otherwise it will be much more complicated to have images due to the high dimensionality in the case for 128x128 for example. It seems to be a much better idea to perform it using extracted features.

Comment: Ok if you have extracted features, then it should mean, that those features embed spatial information, so it is like a pretrained convolution type encoder's output.

Comment: @Geeocode yes exactly. It is just that my output is spatial features dedicated to its image. As I commented out in the answer of mac my frames are not necessarily consecutive. From a video of 120 frames, I can keep 10 in different possible ways.

Comment: Ok, but if you did the selection of 10 frames before training manually, what will do it in the real world prediction after then.

Comment: @Geeocode the prediction process could occur offline. It does not need to be in real time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this approach is not going to work.

Video data has **massive** dependence between adjacent frames, with each frame very similar to the last.  There is also a weaker dependence on prior frames, because objects tend to continue to move relative to other objects in similar ways.  Modern video formats use this redundancy to achieve high compression rates by [modelling the motions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_estimation).

This means that your network will have an extremely strong attention on the previous image.  As you suggest, you could subsample frames several seconds apart to destroy much of the dependence on the previous frame, but if you did so I really wonder whether you would find structure at all in the result?  Even if you feed it hand-coded features [optimised for the purpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter_frame#Inter_frame_prediction), there are are few general rules about which features will be in motion and which will not, so what structure can your attention network learn?

The problem of handling video is just radically different from handling sentences.  Video has very complex elements (pictures) that are largely static over time and have locally predictable motions over a few frames in very simple ways.  Text has simple elements (words) in a complex sentence structure with complex dependence extending over many words.  These differences mean they require fundamentally different approaches.

Comment: A way to overcome the issue of adjacent frames, as I thought is to sub-sample from the whole video of 2-3 second 10 frames (out of 90). In such way, the adjacent frames have different of 8 frames and do not correspond to the same characteristics,

Comment: @mac I think there is a way to overcome the issue of dependency between adjacent frames. You need to consider that my whole video constitutes of 120 frames. I can somehow sub-sample from the whole video to choose some of the frames.

Comment: Quite correct, just a bit amendment: video data can have massive dependence  between adjacent frames but not always has. A lot of video have some text like sequence e.g. a video where adjacent cuts show different people's face with different emotion and different faces can show the same emotion like in the case of two similar meaning words.